# Can awk print lines that do not have a pattern?

Tags: awk

Can awk print all lines that did not match one of the patterns?

In other words, I want to transform some lines but leave the rest unchanged.  So, if a /pattern/ matched I would provide a custom block to print the line.  I just need to provide a default matcher (like an else) to print the other lines.

Comment: Its better you give an example, and what you like to have.  With reputation on 600 points, you should know how important this is.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can negate the pattern to get `else` like behavior:

```
awk '
    /pattern/ {
        # custom block to print the line    
    }
    !/pattern/ {
        # else do other things
    }
'
```

Comment: You would normal not do this.  If you put a `next` in the found block,    the other block will be a not found block.  `awk '/pattern/ {do this;next} {else this block will be run}'`. In your example both test will always be run, and may slow the program some down.

Comment: This `!/pattern/` form is handy in instances like this: `awk '/^IpExt/ && !/Mcast/ {print $4}' /proc/net/netstat`  . In other words, it finds a line that matches a pattern but then excludes a line matching the other pattern.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, just use any non-zero number and awk will do its default thing which is to print the line:

```
awk '7' file
```

If you want it as an "else", put "next" after whatever lines you select for special processing so this one isn't executed for them too.

```
awk '/pattern/{special processing; next} 7' file
```

Comment: You better edit and update your answer before [Kent](http://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent) sees it. `7` is a registered trademark.

Comment: Let's hope he sees imitation of his masterly style as flattery... :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
awk '/pattern/ {do something with line} 1' file
```

Here the `1` will print all lines, both the changed and the not changed line.

---

Just to show the solution `Askan` posted using `else if`

```
awk '{
    if (/pattern/)
        print "Line number:",NR,"pattern matched"
    else if (/Second/) 
        print "Line number:",NR,"Second matched"
    else 
        print "Line number:",NR,"Another line matched"
    }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switch` if you are using `gawk` for example

```
awk '{switch ($0) {
case /pattern/:
    print "Line number:",NR,"pattern matched"
    break

case /Second/:
    print "Line number:",NR,"Second matched"
    break

default:
    print "Line number:",NR,"Another line matched"

}}' input.txt
```

input.txt

```
This line matches the pattern
Second line does not match
Hello
This line also matches the pattern
Another line
```

Output:

```
Line number: 1 pattern matched
Line number: 2 Second matched
Line number: 3 Another line matched
Line number: 4 pattern matched
Line number: 5 Another line matched
```

You can also group the cases by removing the `break` between them. [more info](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Switch-Statement.html)

Comment: I have nearly not see anyone use the `switch` function used here or other places.  Most people tend do use `if else if else`.  Se my updated post.

Comment: Never knew this feature even existed (I fully take the blame of never reading the GNU doc completely). +1 for sharing.

Comment: @JS웃 I have seen it, but fund it seldom used compare to same solution I have added in my post. And what I posted will be portable, not only `gnu awk`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour" | 
  awk '{a=1} /one/ {print 1;a=0} /three/ {print 3;a=0} a'

1
two
3
four
```

Answer (score 1):

awk '!/pattern/ {print}' input
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`0` boolean false
`1` boolean true

```bash
awk -v somevar="replacement" '
    match($0, /^(.*)tag=(.*)$/, m)   { print m[1] "tag=" somevar; matched=1 } 
    match($0, /^(.*)other=(.*)$/, m) { print m[1] "other=" somevar; matched=1 } 
    !matched                         { print }
    matched=0
'
```

if you just have one "thing" you want to replace in a line you may simplify to: (`next` statement forces awk to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record)

`1` == true ==> print the current record whatever it is
instead of `1` you also can write `{ print }`

```bash
awk -v somevar="replacement" '
    match($0, /^(.*)pre(.*)$/, m) { print m[1] "pre:" somevar ; next }
    1
'
```