# trying to make two changes to each line of a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to match a string to a line and then make two changes to the line. For example, for the line "Godfather, The", I want to match ", The", delete ", The" and add "The " to the beginning of the line to produce "The Godfather". I've tried sed and everything else I know (which admittedly isn't much), but can only make one change to the line and not two. Any help?

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers and sorry for the late reply. All of these solutions worked:  [1] sed -E 's/^(.*), The$/The \1/' Movies.txt   [2] sed -E 's/^(.+), The$/The \1/' Movies.txt   [3] sed '/, The$/{s///;s/^/The /}' Movies.txt. I did not try the perl script.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e 'asdf ttrt\nGodfather, The' | gawk '/, The/{gsub(", The", ""); print "The " $0; next} 9'
asdf ttrt
The Godfather
```

First the matching line is found (`/, The/`).
Only for matching line (`{gsub(...), ...}`) the matched pattern is removed, and whole remaining line is printed with `"The "` prepended.
The `next` is there to print matching line only once (with `The`  prepended, then stop processing current line and got to next line).
The `9` is just non-zero number to instruct gawk to print also non-matching lines.

Link or two:

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/awk-find-and-replace-fields-values/
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html
- [Can awk print lines that do not have a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478755/can-awk-print-lines-that-do-not-have-a-pattern)

Comment: There are also lines that end in ", An" that I want preserved intact when I am changing all the ", A" strings. Otherwise "Autumn Afternoon, An", for example, would end up as "A Autumn Afternoonn". Can I use a regular expression to search only for ", A" and leave the ", An"s alone?  I'm using cat to send the file through the command, if that matters.

Comment: I'm using the command cat testfile | gawk '/, A\b/{gsub(", A", ""); print "A " $0; next} 9' but it doesn't work as expected. Does gawk somehow work differently than awk?

Comment: I can use sed -E 's/, A\b//g' to discriminate between ", A" and ", An" but I can't seem to get it to work with gawk.

Answer (score 1):

It's one transaction in `sed`.

```
echo  'Godfather, The' | sed -E 's/^(.+), The$/The \1/'
The Godfather
```

If you want 2, make them separate operations in the script.

```
echo  'Godfather, The' | sed -E 's/^(.+), The$/The \1/; s/Godfather/Exorcist/;'
The Exorcist
```

or

```
echo  'Godfather, The' | 
  sed -E 's/^(.+), The$/The \1/
          s/Godfather/Exorcist/'
The Exorcist
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl :

```
perl -pe 's/(.*), The$/The $1/' <<< "Godfather, The"
# output :
# The Godfather
```

or sed :

```
sed -E 's/^(.*), The$/The \1/' <<< "Godfather, The"
```

Answer (score 0):

No capture groups necessary with sed.

`sed '/, The$/{s///;s/^/The /}'`

On lines ending in `, The`, delete that ending with `s///` (repeats previous match and replaces it with nothing).  Then, add `The`  at the beginning of the line.